# Make netbeans attach maven sources to artifacts

Tags: maven-2, netbeans

I'm having some issues with a third party library that I'd like to step into. Netbeans provides a "Download Sources" option when the libraries node is right clicked. This downloads the sources from svn correctly, a source icon is attached to the dependency node, all is peachy. However, when I open one of the classes it gives me a generated skeleton just as it would if there was no source attached. Further more when there is a maven source present it seems there is no option to attach a local source manually so I can't work round this.

What are everyone else's experiences of this feature?

FYI the library in question is smack 3.1.0
http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Pascal writes, the resolution of source artifacts happens via convention, so if the dependency is at:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.yourcompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>yourartifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

it will look for the source artifact at:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.yourcompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>yourartifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

So what you can do is download the source from  the [source download page](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/source.jsp), create a jar from it and run [install:install-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) as seen [on the usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=your-created-source.jar \
                         -DgroupId=jivesoftware \
                         -DartifactId=smack \
                         -Dversion=3.1.0 \
                         -Dclassifier=sources \
                         -Dpackaging=jar \
                         -DgeneratePom=false
```

That way the convention will work and netbeans will find your sources automatically.

EDIT: added packaging

Comment: +1 for providing a step by step practical workaround (and thus really answering the question)

Comment: Did the trick, though I needed to add -Dpackaging=jar to get it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Netbeans provides a "Download Sources" option when the libraries node is right clicked. This downloads the sources from svn correctly, a source icon is attached to the dependency node, all is peachy.

If we're talking about Maven here, I don't think that this is what is happening. The **Download Sources** feature tells Maven to download a `sources` artifact (e.g. `foo-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar`) for a given dependency **from a Maven repository**. And obviously, this only works if a given dependency is providing a `-sources` jar. But that's not the case of [`smack-3.1.0`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jivesoftware/smack/3.1.0/).

Comment: Seems to be correct, The part that confused me is that the pom has a scm element which contains a svn repo. Netbeans also provides a check out sources option on individual dependencies so I thought it was the same mechanism for the download sources option.